# NavigationBar contents disappear on pop from view with prefersStatusBarHidden = YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a fairly straightforward setup in my iPhone app, with a navigation controller and a view controller. The view controller has a title, and for most of my views, pushing other view controllers works as expected: the title is used as the label for the "back" button on the navigation bar, and the new view is shown. After the new view has been popped from the stack, the old view is shown with its title.

However, as soon as the pushed view controller implements prefersStatusBarHidden with the return value YES, the title in the navigation bar is gone after this view is popped from the stack - it remains empty and doesn't even display my custom rightbarbuttonitem.

Additionally, doing this in landscape instead of portrait does not show this behaviour - the title is displayed correctly. If you encounter this issue in portrait, you could turn the phone to landscape and back to portrait again, and the title and everything else will reappear in place.

I am unsure if this was already there in previous versions of iOS, but I am currently seeing it with iOS 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and the workaround for me was this:

In the view controller that is having **prefersStatusBarHidden** set to YES add:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: This sort of works, but be aware that it messes up the interactive pop gesture. Tapping and dragging the left edge back and forward repeatedly will run viewWillDisappear multiple times. Somehow that causes UINavigationController to get its VC stack confused, sometimes resulting in an infinite cycle of back buttons (click back, animation happens, but no VC is popped off the stack).

Comment: Works for me, and even though I don't like the solution much, I'll accept it as an answer until someone provides a better one... thanks!

Comment: Submitted a bug report to bugreport.apple.com with an id: 19416305. Duplicate if you can, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is because prefersStatusBarHidden is a app wide setting, not per view controller.

You may be able to get around this by adding to the pushed view controllers ViewWillDisappear method

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is an app-wide setting since it is a method which should be overridden by a view controller which doesn't want to show the status bar. The status bar itself behaves as expected, it disappears on push and reappears on pop - explicitly showing it in viewwilldisappear doesn't help here, unfortunately.